# php: How to add generically values to a multidimensional array without incrementing the count

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this...

```
$routes = array();
loop starts...
    $routes[]['location1'] = MyValue1
    $routes[]['location2'] = MyValue2
    $routes[]['distance'] =  MyValue3
...loop ends
```

What I want is this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [location1] => MyValue1
            [location2] => MyValue2
            [distance] => MyValue3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [location1] => MyValue1
            [location2] => MyValue2
            [distance] => MyValue3
        )
}
```

But what I get is this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [location1] => MyValue1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [location2] => MyValue2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [distance] => MyValue3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [location1] => MyValue1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [location2] => MyValue2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [distance] => MyValue3
        )
}
```

What is the correct syntax to use? Or do I need to add some kind of counter to count the iterations through the loop using something like `$routes[$a]['distance']` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to build your sub-array, then add it in a single assignment:

```
$routes = array();
loop starts...
    $routes[] = array (
        'location1' => MyValue1,
        'location2' => MyValue2,
        'distance' =>  MyValue3
    );
...loop ends
```

Every time you do anything with `$routes[]`, you add an element to `$routes`. So, you must either do the above or keep track of the index you are working with.

Comment: I was just testing it... gimme a second! :)

Answer (score 0):

This can work too:

```
$routes=Array(
"0"=>Array
(
        'location1' => 'MyValue1',
        'location2' => 'MyValue2',
        'distance' => 'MyValue3'
),
"1"=>Array
    (
        'location1' => 'MyValue1',
        'location2' => 'MyValue2',
        'distance' => 'MyValue3'
    )
);
```

Comment: Very true - the problem with this solution, however, is that I don't know how many iterations the loop will go through. I was hoping to avoid adding a messy loop counter and I knew there would be a simple, generic `$arr[] = value` type answer.